# Number of similar columns occurrences

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sql-insert

I am new to SQL SERVER and need your advise on something.
I have a big table with stores information. Here is bench_id column:

```
**bench_id**
31
51
51
61
61
61
71
71
```

I have created another small table with two columns:

```
**distinct_bench**           **number**
-----------------------------

31                               1
51                               2
61                               3
71                               2
```

The second table's NUMBER column is showing the number of bench_id's occurrences.
I have tried this code:

```
insert into [dbo].BATCH_ID (batch_id, number)
select 
     distinct [dbo].big_table.batch_id,
           (select count([dbo].big_table.batch_id) from [dbo].big_table)
     from [dbo].big_table
```

But can not get the right answer I am expecting with number of bench_id occurrences.
Can you point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have `GROUP BY` clause since you need to use `COUNT()` to count the occurence of `benchID`.

```
INSERT INTO BATCH_ID (distinct_bench), number)
SELECT  benchID as distinct_bench, COUNT(*) number
FROM    big_table
GROUP   BY BATCH_ID
```

Comment: hey thank you! one more question, in case when big_table.bench_id will be updaited how to do so the BATCH_ID table will also updates? is there any possible way?

Comment: uhmm, what do you mean `BATCH_ID` will also update? do you mean to delete those duplicates on the table?

Comment: no i mean when new code will be inserted in big_table.batch_id column, what to do so that new code will be also visible im small table?