# SQL SERVER: data insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry guys! I just dont know what to do with this task.
The data is the same as in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15538639/number-of-similar-columns-occurences), but what to do in case when I insert new data in big_table.bench_id and i want this data be visible also in BATCH_ID table?
I have tried to bound them with keys, but big_table already has main key so dont know what to do. Please any advice will be appreciated.

Big_table.bench_id:

```
**bench_id**
31
51
51
61
61
61
71
71
```

I have created another BATCH_ID table with two columns:

```
**distinct_bench**           **number**
-----------------------------

31                               1
51                               2
61                               3
71                               2
```

So for example, if i will add new code to the big_table.bench_id like '111':

```
**bench_id**
    31
    51
    51
    61
    61
    61
    71
    71
    111
```

so it will also appears in another table:

```
**distinct_bench**           **number**
    -----------------------------

    31                               1
    51                               2
    61                               3
    71                               2
    111                              1
```

Comment: How do u get the value for the column `number` in your `Batch_Id` table for `distinct_bench = 111` ?

Comment: it is just random value...in the future the new records will be inserted into the table, so what to do to make appear that new records also in second table?

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need another table? You can create a view to achieve that.

```
create table xxTemp (bench_id int) ;

insert into xxTemp (bench_id) 
values (31)
    ,(51)
    ,(51)
    ,(61)
    ,(61)
    ,(61)
    ,(71)
    ,(71) ;

create view xxTempCount as 
Select  bench_id
    , COUNT(1) number 
From    xxTemp
Group By bench_id ;

select *
from xxTempCount ;

insert into xxTemp (bench_id) 
values (111) ;

select *
from xxTempCount ;
```

Elmer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a table for that purpose, you can create a view that will return you the desired information. For example, try following:

```
CREATE VIEW vwBigTable
AS
    SELECT bench_id AS [**distinct_bench**], COUNT(*) AS [**number**]
    FROM big_table
    GROUP BY bench_id
```

And then:

```
SELECT * FROM vwBigTable
```